# Failure of Bash $@ variable

Tags: bash

I've done this several times, and it never seems to work properly. Can anyone explain why?

```
function Foobar
{
  cmd -opt1 -opt2 $@
}
```

What this is *supposed* to do is make it so that calling `Foobar` does the same thing as calling `cmd`, but with a few extra parameters (`-opt1` and `-opt2`, in this example).

Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly. It works OK if all your arguments lack spaces. But if you want an argument with spaces, you write it in quotes, and Bash helpfully strips away the quotes, breaking the command. How do I prevent this incorrect behavior?

Comment: @isaach1000 That's not relevant, because `$@` isn't a user-defined variable name -- it's the POSIX-specified name used to access the list of arguments to the current script or function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to double-quote the `$@`to keep bash from performing the unwanted parsing steps (word splitting etc) after substituting the argument values:

```
function Foobar
{
  cmd -opt1 -opt2 "$@"
}
```

EDIT from the Special Parameters section of the bash manpage:

```
@   Expands to the positional parameters, starting from  one.   When
    the  expansion  occurs  within  double  quotes,  each  parameter
    expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1"
    "$2"  ...   If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word,
    the expansion of the first parameter is joined with  the  begin-
    ning  part  of  the original word, and the expansion of the last
    parameter is joined with the last part  of  the  original  word.
    When  there  are no positional parameters, "$@" and $@ expand to
    nothing (i.e., they are removed).
```

Comment: Doesn't that just expand `$@` and then treat all of its contents as a single word?

Comment: Nope, `$@` is treated specially in that respect.

Comment: ...OK... arbitrary special-case rules FTW! :-/

Comment: Do you mean "bash" not "bask"?

Comment: I'm new to bash by the way. Can I ask: what is `cmd`? Is that a real command?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: indeed.  I think in Bourne's original shell (or perhaps even some earlier variant) $@ expanded to `$1" "$2" "$3` for instance, i.e., included double quotes *between* each position parameter but not at the start or end.  As a result in very old sh variants you need ${1+"$@"} as "$@" expands to "" when $@ is empty.

Comment: @0x499602D2: No, `cmd` is just a placeholder for some real command (and similarly `-opt1 -opt2` are placeholders for whatever actual options)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid No, it's not arbitrary or special-case. Array expansion works the exact same way.